# No "hourglass" appears

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

Access 2016-2019. I have one form with MyTextbox and MyCombobox with one GotFocus event.
When the cursor is on MyTextbox and I click on MyCombobox, I expect a hourglass to appear during the while loop (2 seconds), but the cursor remains as a pointer. Why? Is there any other way to accomplish the same thing?

```
Private Sub MyCombobox_GotFocus()
  DoCmd.Hourglass True ' or Screen.MousePointer = 11
  DoEvents
  DoCmd.Hourglass True ' or Screen.MousePointer = 11
  Debug.Print "A"
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To 2000000000: Next i ' Do some heavy stuff for about 2 seconds
  Debug.Print "B"
  DoCmd.Hourglass False
End Sub
```

Comment: `DoEvents` will allow other code to set the cursor.

Comment: No hourglass even if I repeat ```DoCmd.Hourglass True``` after ```DoEvents``` (or remove ```DoEvents```)

Comment: Don't burn your CPU looping 2 billion times just to wait for 2 seconds - there's a native `Sleep()` method you can add to your VBA project. Also, try the above code in a button `Click()` event to see if it works.

Comment: Don't do this. Never let the user wait for nothing.

Comment: The user is not waiting for "nothing". The user is waiting for the hourglass to appear. And the only user running the application is myself. Why shouldn't I let myself wait for two seconds for the hourglass?

Comment: You add DoEvents AFTER Do.Cmd.Hourglass True - not BEFORE. You should also add DoEvents inside your loop

Comment: But... As you can see, the DoEvents is BOTH before and after DCmd.Horglass true. And in the real world, there is no way to add DoEvents inside the loop because the delay occurs when the combobox is filled from an ADO request to SQL server. The for loop is just to simplify my question.